# Is it sinful to use a captions name different than what it is for?

Tags: halal-haram, lying

I want to to add tafsirs into my [videos,](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJv0STX-xSkapow54orIJ6g) but in order for the viewer to activate it, they'll have to choose it from the menu of language captions. For example: in [this video,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kL957Z-omJU) if you go to captions and click on Arabic it will show the tafsir of Ibn Katheer, but if I wanted to add tafsir Al-Baghawi (in Arabic, because I want to give the viewer the option of viewing multiple tafasir, and I'll put the names of the tafasir and what language they should click to view them in description in shaa Allah, and to make it clear, the tafasir will be Arabic), am I allowed to choose another language such as German or Japanese or would that be haram because it's kind of acting dishonestly? or perhaps haram because it's using a service different to what it was supposed to be used for?